# Неграмотное построение предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь

Прошу помочь разрешить спор двух повёрнутых на знании русского языка пенсионеров: правильно ли составлена фраза: "Каждый из них охарактеризовал Вас душевно больным на базе графомании и не владеющего логикой построения всего текста". Я считаю, что надо писать владеющИМ. Кроме того, в шестидесятые слово душевнобольной писалось слитно. Спасибо.

Comment: Еще я бы заменил "на базе", скажем, "на почве". А то как-то коряво звучит.

Comment: С минимумом корректуры: "*Каждый из них охарактеризовал вас душевнобольным на базе графомании и не владеющим логикой построения всего текста".
*"Каждый из них охарактеризовал вас как душевнобольного на базе графомании и не владеющего логикой построения всего текста".*

Comment: Hermit, дык еще проще можно.
[i]Каждый из них охарактеризовал вас как душевнобольного на базе графомании и [b]как[/b] не владеющего логикой построения всего текста".[/i] 
Вопрос-то не в том, как откорректировать, а в том, кто из двух спорящих пенсионеров заслуживает такой оценки.))))

Comment: Dear Hermit, и кому Вы присудили бы такую оценку?

Comment: Я оценок не выставлял! И не хочу.

Comment: >кому Вы присудили бы такую оценку?    
  
Я комнату взглядом окинул,   
Как будто узором пленен.   
Мне нравятся очень *обои* -      
Сказал им и выбежал вон.      
(Козьма Петрович)

Comment: Dear Behemothus! 
Рас уш Вам нравятся абои (как Быков в "Служили два товарища" выразился: "Абои полетим!"), то оценка должна получиться непредвзятой. Простите за назойливость, абоим она, старым пер соналиям, важна.
Thank you very much.

Comment: > ДОБЛЕСТНЫЕ СТУДИОЗУСЫ
Класс! Я даже поэзию начала любить!

Answer (score 1):

Я не крупнейший специалист в области языкознания (поэтому высказываюсь исключительно для поддержания разговора), - возможно, именно в силу этого обстоятельства я не встречала случаев, когда глагол "охарактеризовать" управляет творительным падежом прилагательного или причастия. Я сталкивалась только со случаями, когда этот глагол  распространяется обстоятельством, выраженным оборотом с союзом "как" (по непонятным причинам в толковом словаре Ушакова этот оборот отделяется запятой от предшествующих слов).

> Еще я бы заменил "на базе", скажем, "на почве". А то как-то коряво звучит.

"На почве", безусловно, более удачный вариант. Но далеко не идеальный, на мой взгляд. Возможно, куда поэтичнее звучало бы что-то вроде "каждый из них признал вас душевнобольным, как графомана".

Определение "всего" при существительном "текст" как минимум избыточно. Если текст строится в соответствии с определенной логикой, то этой логике подчиняются все его элементы. Если необходимо указать на нарушение логики в построении отдельных, например, фраз в тексте, - логики, которой должны подчиняться эти фразы, а не текст, - сообщаете о нарушении логики в построении отдельных фраз. Я сама не вижу смысла в собственных объяснениях, но поверьте: доказать, что слово "всего" здесь излишне, не легче, чем доказать аксиому.

> Кроме того, в шестидесятые слово душевнобольной писалось слитно.

Ваши знания относительно написания слова "душевнобольной" актуальны.

Comment: Спасибо, Ноир!
Пожалуй, Вы правы: охарактеризовать как ...
2. Оппонент мой "совсем не блондинка", о какой там поэзии может идти речь.
3. Согласен с Вами. Тем более, если речь идет о "логике построения". Припахивает "размышлизмами о гусударстве" героя Шукшина.
4. К сожалению, оппонент считает, что слово душевнобольной можно писать и слитно, и раздельно. Его "политическое кредо": "Когда я прав, а прав всегда я". Тяжелый случай.

Comment: > Тяжелый случай

Ну мы уже так и поняли. Однако поиск способов выражения мысли, соответствующих нормам лексической и синтаксической сочетаемости, - это всегда тяжелый случай.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если исходить из ожидаемого смысла, то разумеется "... больным... и не владеющим...".
А вот исходная фраза означала бы, что "каждый охарактеризовал Вас... и (еще кого-то) *не владеющего...*".

Маленькое наблюдение. Если исключить последний смысл и признать грамматическую ошибку, то все это заставляет вспомнить давешнее наблюдение (если интересно, найду ссылки), что в "русском разговорном" все косвенный падежи причастного оборота благополучно заменяются родительным вопреки требуемым правилам согласования.

Comment: Dear Behemothus! Прошу простить, что по неопытности обратился не по адресу насчет оценки. Зацените, пожалуйста, этот спор повёрнутых субъектов. Сдается, что правила согласования таки надо исполнять.
Спасибо.

Comment: Нет, сэр! "Абои плетим" ента таки Быков, светлой памяти. А что касается Коха с Вагнером, то, может, обоев при них не клеили. Атсель недопонимание. Дык как там у нас с присягой? Оценкой, то бишь.

Comment: Нет, сэр. 
Когда я употреблял свою фразу, ни о каком Быкове не думал.
Это Козьма Прутков. А с Быковым разбирайтесь сами. Он мне в данной теме неинтересен.  
Честь имею.

Comment: Ноу, сэр! Стихотворение, слов нет, изящное, но в ДАННОЙ ТЕМЕ "Абои полетим" гораздо интереснее. Примите, и пр.